# Override ActiveRecord::Base find method (to accept non-default id field as a search parameter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have followed [this](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/) tutorial on how to accept not-only-numeric `primary key id` when creating instance of my `ModelName` in my **Ruby on Rails** application.

Everything is okay, but there is a paragraph:

> Be aware that Product.find won’t work anymore, and other Rails helper that relies on `id` will stop functioning. **If you really want that, you need to override more methods and this seems too much of a pain for me**. So I’d highly recommend you to leave `#id` as is.

The question is: when I am trying to get instance of my model by using `.find()` method in my `ModelNameController` it doesn't work (I think that's because of `.find()` method's search parameters - it does find something by `id` field which is numeric)

I have this piece of code:

```
def set_model_name
  @model_name = ModelName.find(params[:hashid])
end
```

Where `:hashid` is a parameter that is a string (I'd like to use a string instead of a number)

How could I solve my problem?

One of the solutions would be overriding `ActiveRecord::Base`'s `.find()` method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the article, `find` should work as long as you don't override the `id` methods.  Are you doing this?  If so, why?

Comment: My aim is to not use `id` but use another type of primary key field.
In my case it was a string.

Comment: Right. But the tutorial says you can add `self.primary_key = 'hashid'` to your model and it will use that as the id instead of the id column. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Didn't noticed that. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to override the default behaviour of `find`. Instead, you can use the [find_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) method:

```
def set_model_name
  @model_name = ModelName.find_by(hashid: params[:hashid])
end
```